# Multi-sided many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql

I'm trying to think of a solution to a mapping problem in which I can relate two seemingly unrelated groups.  So, lets say I have a set of attributes, A, an Entity Group 1, and an Entity Group 2.  I could easily have a many-many relationship between 1 and A and do queries like

```
select * from 1 
  inner join a_1 on a_1.1_id = 1.id
  inner join a on a.id = a_1.a_id
  where a.attr = '123'
```

I could obviously do something similar with A related to 2.  What I'm trying to actually query though is A to 2 and A to 1 where the elements in group 1 and 2 share the same attribute in A.  So, if the attribute I'm storing is an address, I want to be able to select out all people in group 1 and group 2 that share addresses, and what those addresses are.

Appreciate the help!

EDIT:

Table structure:

```
t1 -----< t1_A >------ A ------< t2_A >------ t2

t1[id, other], t1_A[id, t1id, Aid], A[id, address], t2_A[id, t2id, Aid], t2[id, other]
```

And the goal is to get a row returned for every element in t1 that has the same address as an element in t2(as well as what that address is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> query though is A to 2 and A to 1 where the elements in group 1 and 2
>   share the same attribute in A.

I think you are looking for `UNION`:

```
select address, ... -- and other properties
from table1 t1 
inner join a on a.a_id = t1.id
where a.attr = '123'
UNION ALL
select address, ... -- and other properties
from table2 t2 
inner join a on a.a_id = t2.id
where a.attr = '123'
```

---

**Update:**

Considering the tables' structures, after updating your question:

**t1:**

- `id`,
- ...

**t1_A:**

- `id`,
- `t1id`,
- `Aid`,
- ...

**A:**

- `id`,
- `address`,
- ...

**t2_A:**

- `id`,
- `t2id`,
- `Aid`,
- ...

**t2:**

- `id`,
- ...

So, you want to get:

> And the goal is to get a row returned for every element in t1 that has
>   the same address as an element in t2(as well as what that address is).

Then you can do this:

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  A.*
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t1_A ON t1.id = t1_A.t1id
INNER JOIN A    ON A.id  = t1_A.Aid
INNER JOIN t2_A ON a.id  = t2_A.aid
INNER JOIN t2   ON t2.id = t2_A.t2id;
```

Comment: Ah, that's looking like it's on the right path, but I actually don't want the where clauses.  I want it to return ALL items in t1, the address in attributes, and the items it's related to in t2.  So I want any items in t1 and t2 that share any attributes in A(and what all those relationships look like).

Comment: @WilliamThurston OK, then remove the `WHERE` clause, also can you please show me the tables' structures and what is those attributes that relates each others with some sample data? it will be very helpful. thanks

Comment: @WilliamThurston - See my edit, hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Trying it out!  I'll let you know.  Appreciate your fast response.

Comment: Worked great, I added t2.* to my select as well to get both ends.